# please help me fix No enum constant

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

**Enum class**

```java
@Getter
public enum Role {
    USER("user"), ADMIN("admin");

    String roleText;

    Role(String roleText) {
        this.roleText = roleText;
    }

    public String getRoleText() {
        return this.roleText;
    }


}
```

**Query to update DB**

```java
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("update User user set user.role = :userRole where user.id = :id")
void assignRole(@Param("id") long id, @Param("userRole") Role userRole);
```

**Service for query**

```java
public void assignRole(long id, Role role) throws Exception {

        if (isExists(id)) {

            User user = repository.findById(id)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UserDoesntExistException("user doesnt exist id ::" + id));

            if (user.getRole() == Role.ADMIN) {
                throw new UserIsAdminException(" user is an admin , their roles cant be changed");
            }           
            repository.assignRole(id, role);
        }

        else
            throw new  UserDoesntExistException("user doesnt exist id ::" + id);
    }
```

**Controller for service**

/** Admin can assign roles to other users **/

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/user/{id}/role")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUserRole(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody String role) {

        try {

            Role parsedRole = Role.valueOf(role.toUpperCase().trim());
            userService.assignRole(id, parsedRole);         
            System.out.println(parsedRole);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(parsedRole,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage().toString(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }
```

tried to assign new roles to users ... only admin can do that assignment

I updated a user role to admin to do request my self in the terminal ... which works because the other admin only requests work except for updating user role enums

**Postman Requests**

tried --> "ADMIN"
tried ---> {
"role": "ADMIN"
}

both give --->. No enum constant com.edd.bookrental.models.user.Role."ADMIN"

Comment: It would be really nice if you could read the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and then fix your use of a single backtick, new line, triple backticks around code blocks. Code blocks are triple backtick, new line, lines of code, new line, triple backtick. No single backticks involved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a snippet to replicate how you used the ENUM and it worked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Testing enum!");

    String input = "ADMIN";
    Role parsedRole = Role.valueOf(input.toUpperCase().trim());
    System.out.println(parsedRole.getRoleText());
}
```

Here is my output.

> Testing enum!

> admin

My guess is that the "Role" you imported in your Controller is different from the ENUM "Role" you created. Check if the Role you have is imported from other packages.